# Visual Composer conflicting with enqueued custom script

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, visual-composer

I have a wordpress page with Visual composer and a custom theme.
The custom theme contains a script. Everything works fine until i use wp_enqueue_script for my custom script. All js-related functions by VC cease to work.
Do i have to enqueue VC scripts? How can i achieve this?

```
 require_once('wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php');

add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "adapt_enqueue");
add_action('init', 'register_main_menu');
function adapt_enqueue()
{
//VC Works if i remove this line:
   wp_enqueue_script('app', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', ['jquery'], 5.0);
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(),5.0);
```

Comment: where are you trying to enqueue script , can you paste code here for enqueue script

Comment: wp_enqueue_script('app', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', ['jquery'], 5.0);  // Functions.php of the theme